# Strange Issue: Application does not show in Main Menu after installation

Tags: symbian, symbian3

I am developing an application for Symbian S60 V3. The application can be run properly on Simulator on PC. It can be transferred to Phone. On Phone, it can be clicked to installed. But after installation, I cannot find the installed application for running. It just disappear.

Is there any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the application with user interface? If it's just some bacjground process without icon and GUI then it won't be visible.
Did you check under Applications link (or Installed or whatever it is called in different systems).
Do you see your app listed in Settings -> Application Manager?

Comment: Thanks. I checked that it is the option of compiler that we chose ARMxxx and it should be GCC.